# not all arguments converted during string formatting.. NO % variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

```
x = input()
y = 1 
print (x)
while 1 == y:
if x == 1:
    y == y + 1
elif x % 2 == 0: #even
    x = x // 2
    print (x)
else:
    x = 3 * x + 1
    print (x)
```

If you know what the Collatz conjecture is, I'm trying to make a calculator for that. I want to have x as my input so I don't have to change x's number and save every time I want to try out a new number.

I get below error

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting' 
>   at line 7.

Please help a noobie out.

Comment: Note that the code below the while loop isn't correctly indented.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you take user input:

```
x = input()
```

Now `x` is a `str`. So, on this line:

```
    elif x % 2 == 0: #even
```

The [`%` operator](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) acts as a *string interpolation operator*.

```
>>> mystring = "Here goes a string: %s and here an int: %d" % ('FOO', 88)
>>> print(mystring)
Here goes a string: FOO and here an int: 88
>>>
```

However, the `input` you gave does not have a format specifier, thus:

```
>>> "a string with no format specifier..." % 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>>
```

You need to convert your user input into an `int` for the `%` operator to perform the modulo operation.

```
x = int(input())
```

Now, it will do what you want:

```
>>> x = int(input("Gimme an int! "))
Gimme an int! 88
>>> x % 10
8
>>>
```