# Reason and suggestion for: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Why this error is occurring and how can I fix it?
I am trying to write this code as a practice in codewars.

```
def iq_test(numbers):
    splitted_num=numbers.split()
    list_numbers= list(splitted_num)#splitted string was already a list
    odds = [x for x in list_numbers if x%2!=0]
    evens= [x for x in list_numbers if x%2==0]
    return (odds.index[0, 1] if len(odds)<len(evens) else evens[0, 1])


numbers= ("2 4 7 8 10")
print(iq_test(numbers))
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Desktop\Python Exercises\codewars\9_IQ Test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(iq_test(numbers))
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Desktop\Python Exercises\codewars\9_IQ Test.py", line 8, in iq_test
    odds = [x for x in list_numbers if x%2!=0]
  File "C:\Users\Masoud\Desktop\Python Exercises\codewars\9_IQ Test.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    odds = [x for x in list_numbers if x%2!=0]
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

**This is the question:**

Bob is preparing to pass IQ test. The most frequent task in this test is to find out which one of the given numbers differs from the others. Bob observed that one number usually differs from the others in evenness. Help Bob — to check his answers, he needs a program that among the given numbers finds one that is different in evenness, and return a position of this number. Question: ! Keep in mind that your task is to help Bob solve a real IQ test, which means indexes of the elements start from 1 (not 0)

Comment: When you split your string you get a list of smaller strings. You need to convert your strings into ints.

Comment: See [not all arguments converted during string formatting.. NO % variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499191/not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-no-variables)

Comment: just convert the string x into int while taking the modulus as you cannot take the modulus of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was your objective 
Bob is preparing to pass IQ test. The most frequent task in this test is to find out which one of the given numbers differs from the others. Bob observed that one number usually differs from the others in evenness. Help Bob — to check his answers, he needs a program that among the given numbers finds one that is different in evenness, and return a position of this number. Question: ! Keep in mind that your task is to help Bob solve a real IQ test, which means indexes of the elements start from 1 (not 0)

This should do it

```
def iq_test(numbers):
    splitted_num=numbers.split()
    # to make all the strings to characters
    list_numbers = list(map(int,splitted_num))
    odds = [x for x in list_numbers if x%2!=0]
    evens= [x for x in list_numbers if x%2==0]
    # you're trying to return the index of the different number among the given list 
    # + 1 is that for index starts at 0 so the position will be index + 1 
        return list_numbers.index(odds[0])+1 if len(odds) == 1 else list_numbers.index(evens[0])+1

numbers = ("2 4 7 8 10")
print(iq_test(numbers))
```

Comment: Doesnt work for even nums e.g. numbers = ("1 2 1 1")

Comment: This should do it

Comment: @Max: @Tonystark has just accepted a simplifying edit (there was no need for the `lambda`) so you may want to grab a fresh copy of this.

Answer (score 4):

Your `list_numbers` is a list of strings, `['2', '4', '7', '8', '10']`

When operating on a string, the `%` operator has a different meaning than what it means for integers.  It is probably not worth describing that operation in detail, because its use is no longer recommended, although it relates to string formatting.  It also so happens that the values used in that operation were such as to cause a `TypeError`, but even if it had succeeded, the operation involving strings would still not have given the intended result.

The important thing for the current purpose is that the values in your `list_numbers` need to be converted into `int` and then the `%` operator will do what you intend it to, namely arithmetic modulo.  I would suggest replacing:

```
    list_numbers= list(splitted_num)
```

with:

```
    list_numbers = [int(s) for s in splitted_num]
```

You also have errors in your `return` statement, because `odds.index[0, 1]` and `evens[0, 1]` are not valid expressions here.  Given the problem which you are trying to solve, you could use something like this:

```
    return 1 + list_numbers.index(
        odds[0] if len(odds) < len(evens) else evens[0])
```

Comment: added the question to the post

Comment: @Max now that you've added the question, I've suggested what the `return` statement could look like.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, just add a line in the function that convert list of string number to list of intergers:

```
def iq_test(numbers):
    splitted_num=numbers.split()
    list_numbers = map(int, splitted_num)
    odds = [x for x in list_numbers if x%2!=0]
    evens= [x for x in list_numbers if x%2==0]
    return (odds if len(odds)<len(evens) else evens)

numbers = ("2 4 7 8 10")
print(iq_test(numbers))
```

Comment: Did you try to run this code snippet , it will throw an TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Just added : list_numbers = [int(x) for x in list_numbers]
Which is not the problem and the error is because of the return statement. Not sure what op wants return.

Comment: always try to debug all the errors and should not post answers with errors

Comment: this is not addressing the question