# Unable to convert arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sort the numbers in a list based on the last digit.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
list1 = sys.argv[1]
list1_split = list1.split(",")

sorted_numbers = sorted(list1_split, key=lambda x: x%10)
print("Sorted numbers are: ", sorted_numbers)
```

This is what I get on the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\john\pythonprojects\test1> testing.py 45,60,51,24,62,49
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\john\pythonprojects\test1\testing.py", line 6, in <module>
    sorted_numbers = sorted(list1_split, key=lambda x: x % 10)
  File "C:\Users\john\pythonprojects\test1\testing.py", line 6, in <lambda>
    sorted_numbers = sorted(list1_split, key=lambda x: x % 10)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The expected output should be: `[60, 51, 62, 24, 45, 49]`

I can't figure out how to solve this error

Comment: `sys.argv[1]` is a string. `list1` is then also a string. `list1_split` then becomes a list of strings. while sorting, each `x` is then also a string. `x % 10` then is calling the `%` operator on a string - which just happens to be the formatting operator for strings. Ans since `x` is not a format string - you get that error.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate (because of the list), but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499191/not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-no-variables

Answer (score 3):

`list1_split` is a list of strings - you need to make them `int`s. A straightforward way of doing this is to use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```py
sorted_numbers = sorted(map(int, list1.split(",")), key=lambda x: x % 10)
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo The question specifically asks for a list of ints as output.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing different format there.

Split method resulting list of strings. If you want to perform modulo operation, typecasting the string into integer would work.

```
sorted_numbers = sorted(list1_split, key=lambda x: int(x)%10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the input numbers are *guaranteed to be non-negative*, the numeric computation `x % 10` is equivalent to a string operation `x[-1]`. Besides converting all strings to numbers, you can also change the lambda function to `lambda x: x[-1]` to make the program work.

Answer (score 0):

The argument you are taking from command line will be stored as string. So all the elements in the `list1_split` list are strings. You cannot perform modulo on them. You can just convert the elements into integer format in the lambda key itself.

like here `sorted_numbers = sorted(list1_split, key=lambda x: int(x)%10)`

Im getting this output.

[image]

Edit: Note that the output is a list of strings. As we have not explicitly converted them to integers.

Comment: Worth noting that (as can be seen from the screenshot) `sorted_numbers` will be a list of **strings** this way

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah sorry my bad, should use a map or list comprehension to make it int.

Comment: It's OK there are others answers for that. I just think it should be added in the answer as a note for clarification